# select option when the model is updated before ng-options is loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-options

I have a "state-select" directive that populates a select element with a list of states based on a countryCode. The directive watches for changes on countryCode to update the attribute provided to ng-options.

I'm trying now from my controller to set both model.countryCode and model.sateCode, but as the state select is populated when countryCode changes, the model value is updated before the options get a chance to get loaded.

How can I make sure the select does select the option referred in its ng-model after I've loaded the options?

Here's my directive:

```
.directive( 'stateSelect', [ 'CDN_VIEW', 'locationService', function( CDN_VIEW, locationService ) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            'ngModel': '=',
            'country': '=',
        },
        link: function stateSelect( $scope, elements, attrs ) {
            $scope.states = null;
            function loadCountryStates( countryCode ) {
                if ( !countryCode ) {
                    return false;
                }

                $scope.ngModel = undefined;
                locationService.getCountryStates( countryCode ).then ( function getStates( states ) {
                    $scope.states = states;
                } );
            }

            $scope.$watch( 'country', loadCountryStates );
        },
        templateUrl: 'states.html'
    };
} ] )
```

the template:

```
<select ng-model="ngModel" ng-options="s.code as s.name for s in states">
    <option value="" disabled>select state</option>
</select>
```

here's the use of the directive:

```
<state-select ng-model="info.stateCode" country="info.countryCode">
```

here's what I'm doing in my controller:

```
function setDetectedLocation( location ) {
    $scope.info.countryCode = location.countryCode;
    $scope.info.stateCode = location.stateCode;
    $scope.info.city = location.city;
}

locationService.getLocation().then( setDetectedLocation, locationError );
```

When I fill the selects manually it works, and if I run the getLocation twice, when the states for the country are already loaded, it works too.

Any pointers?

Comment: I've improved the situation a bit by unlinking the controller's `info.stateCode` from the select `ngModel` and watching for changes on the former. This fixes the first load of the state list, but the problem persists when country select is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this problem. The trick was to disassociate the controller model —the one holding the real value— and the directive's select model —the one holding the selected option. This way I could watch manually changes in both and update values when needed.

Here's the changes to the directive:

```
scope: {
    'ngModel': '=',
    'country': '=',
},
link: function stateSelect( $scope, element, attrs ) {
    $scope.states = null;
    $scope.state = { 'code': undefined };

    function loadCountryStates( countryCode ) { ... }

    $scope.$watch( 'country', loadCountryStates );

    // watch manual change on select
    $scope.$watch( 'state.code', function( stateCode ) {
        $scope.ngModel = stateCode;
    } );

    // watch further changes to the model
    $scope.$watch( 'ngModel', function( stateCode ) {
        if ( stateCode ) {
            $scope.state.code = stateCode;
        }
    } );
}
```

here's the changes to the template:

```
<select ng-model="state.code" ng-options="s.code as s.name for s in states">
</select>
```

note how the select is now linked to the directive's `state.code`, and in turn this is watched and synchronized with the controllers property via `ngModel`.

I don't know why the original way doesn't work, though!

Answer (score -2):

You could create an initStateTo param that when set will init the state value in the directive.

```
     $scope.info.initStateTo = "CA";

     <state-select ng-model="info.stateCode" country="info.countryCode" 
              initStateTo="info.initStateTo">

            $scope.ngModel = undefined;
            locationService.getCountryStates( countryCode ).then (
                function getStates( states ) {
                   $scope.states = states;
                   if($scope.initStateTo) {
                      $scope.ngModel = $scope.initStateTo;
                      $scope.initStateTo = undefined;
                   }
                 } );
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I understand this. What's the difference between the ngModel and initStateTo scope properties, if both are set to the same value, at the same time, from the controller? Wouldn't that be equivalent to $scope.ngModel = $scope.ngModel in the directive? Thanks.

Comment: You indicated that "the model value is updated before the options get a chance to get loaded", this is because setting country causes a service to be called which fills all the states. The solution I suggest will set the state value AFTER the country service has setup all the states such that the value is proper AND SET AFTER all the values are loaded. If that is not what you are trying to do then I am misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: I did try this, but surprisingly the watch callback for the countryCode does not get called on time. I'm guessing Angular waits to the end of the digest cycle to process the callbacks, so it seems there's no way to have the options loaded before the model value is set :\

Comment: That can't be. The promise of the location service call will not return until AFTER the call is completed. That is how a promise works. Perhaps you should post the code for getCountryStates() and there is something wrong in how that is being executed.

Comment: Scott, there was no problem with the promise, but rather with when the watch callback was being executed —which is not right away after the values are modified. So once the promise is resolved, the two scope attributes get updated, and then the watch callbacks are executed. At this point, the stateCode has already been set, so it's too late to base the state options from the set countryCode value.